# about return type in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that has multiple fields which I just need one field. The table called ZipCompare. 
I usually use IQueryable<> as returned type of a linq query. But for the following code, an error comes out said "can not implicitly convert type `System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>` to ZipCompare. Then what return type I should use? I use this function to fill the dropdownlist control
My code is :

```
public IQueryable<ZipCompare> GetStates()
    {
        VettingDataContext dc = new VettingDataContext(_connString);
        dc.DeferredLoadingEnabled = true;
        var query = (from c in dc.ZipCompares
                     select new { States = c.State }).Distinct();
        return query;
    }
```

Front end code:

```
ddl_BilState.DataSource = zipDAL.GetStates();
        ddl_BilState.DataTextField = "States";
        ddl_BilState.DataValueField = "States";
        ddl_BilState.DataBind();
```

This is a .net web application, I write in c#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your query:

```
var query = (from c in dc.ZipCompares
             select new { States = c.State }).Distinct();
```

That isn't selecting a `ZipCompare` - it's selecting an anonymous type. It's not clear what you *are* trying to do, but if you want to return an `IQueryable<ZipCompare>` your `select` clause will need to be select a `ZipCompare`.

If you *don't* want to return a ZipCompare... well, in this case it looks like you don't need an anonymous type. Just use:

```
var query = (from c in dc.ZipCompares
             select c.State).Distinct();
```

Or rather more succinctly:

```
return dc.ZipCompares.Select(c => c.State).Distinct();
```

You then change your data binding to bind to the value itself (use "." as the field perhaps? Or perhaps the empty string? Not sure).

Answer (score 1):

return `IEnumerable<TypeOfStateProperty>`, and change your query not to use an anonymous type.  For instance if `State` is a `StateEnum` value:

```
public IEnumerable<StateEnum> GetStates()
{
    VettingDataContext dc = new VettingDataContext(_connString);
    dc.DeferredLoadingEnabled = true;
    var query = (from c in dc.ZipCompares select c.State ).Distinct();
    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to return a List of string? State looks like a string...

Answer (score 0):

Change your return type to `List<string>` and do this:

```
foreach(var item in query)
{
   myList.Add(item.States);
}
```